# awk doesn't register internal variable intitiations

Tags: bash, variables, awk

```
function func {
awk -v fr="$1" -v ft="$2" '/fr/,/ft/' text.txt }
func "frame 44" "frame 1000"
```

The function is supposed to grab the lines between the matches of frame 44 and frame 1000. However, awk looks for "fr" instead of "frame 44", making for example "frame 1" in the text file a match. How can I resolve this?

Comment: You cannot use `/fr/` to match the input variable `fr`. Use instead `$0 ~ fr`..

Comment: Do you want also to include the lines with `frame 44` and `frame 1000`, or do you just want the lines in between?

Comment: Thanks, didn't know that. No, header and footer matches are not important. What would the difference be then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this command:

```
awk -v fr="$1" -v ft="$2" '
  $0 ~ fr { inFrame=1 }
  inFrame {print}
  $0 ~ ft { inFrame=0 }' text.txt
```

This will also include the header and footer lines.

To skip header and footer, try:

```
$0 ~ fr { inFrame=1; next }
$0 ~ ft { inFrame=0 }
inFrame {print}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using sed instead?

```bash
function func() {
    sed -n "/$1/,/$2/p" text.txt
}
```